# Trigger Spring Security Login on Secured Request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-web

Spring Security "will provide you with a login form"...https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/hellomvc-javaconfig.html

So how can I trigger the built-in form on the secured requests?

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN", "USER").and()
            .withUser("guest").password("guest").roles("USER");
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .httpBasic().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/test").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/test/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/test/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH,"/test/**").hasRole("ADMIN").and()
            .formLogin()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
}
```

When I make a POST to "/test" without signing in, it is correctly prevented and secured, but I'd like Spring to trigger its login form when the request is made from my front-end. Especially without creation of an html file, or a /login Controller, which seems like this feature makes possible.

Comment: did you configure also Security Filter?

Comment: You should remove the call to httpBasic() and use formLogin().loginPage("/login"). See https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/ for a complete example

Comment: @AngeloImmediata is that a Spring class or Java class or xml config? If you were able to link a doc or source....

Comment: Sorry @StefanEmanuelsson but unless I'm missing something from that example, it looks like I'd have to create a front-end  /login.html which is explicitly what I'm trying to get away from. I'd like to not redirect and instead trigger the Spring Security login form while remaining in the view.

Comment: You must not create a login.html; it should be generated by Spring Security if correctly configured. In order to enable it not only you have to create a Configuration class as you did but you need to configure also the web servlet filter.  I configure it in `web.xml` in this way: ` <filter><filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name><filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class></filter><filter-mapping><filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name><servlet-name>MySpringSvlt</servlet-name></filter-mapping>`